# Can't center navbar and have to click the word itself

Tags: html, css, navbar, navigationbar

This is my css code (for the index page):

```
span{
display:block;
font-size:100px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.index {
    background-image: url("images/indexbackground.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 1600px 800px;
}

/*NAVBAR (begin)*/
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: Black;
}

ul {
  background: black;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    color: #white;
  background: black;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 27px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
    background: #DEB887;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
    background: black;
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 17rem;
    position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 27px;
    left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
/*NAVBAR (end)*/
```

---

This is the code for HTML (index page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="piano.css" />
<html class="index">
<head>
<title>The piano - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><span>The Piano</span></center>

<!--(start) NAVBAR-->
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<nav>
<div class="navwrapperindex">
<nav class="navmenuindex">
<ul class="clearfixindex">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a>The piano itself</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="mechanics.html">Mechanics</a></li>
<li><a href="construction.html">Construction</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a>Types of pianos</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="grand.html">Grand</a></li>
<li><a href="upright.html">Upright</a></li>
<li><a href="electric.html">Electric</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="historypianos.html">History of the piano</a>
</li>
<li><a href="pianosongs.html">Piano songs</a>
</li>
</div>
</nav>
<!--(end)NAVBAR-->

</body>
</html>
```

I already tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work...
Right now my index page looks like this:

[(Index page but I had to cut it because the full picture was over 2 mb)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYCPi.png)

(I'm sorry, It's really bad but it's my first time making a website with html and css).

I need to center the navigation bar and to be able to click the box instead of the word.
Thank you for reading (and maybe answering)!

Comment: Hey @Lunette, welcome to SO. Would you be able to post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link here so we can help better troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I recommend to use classes instead of the direct element selector, 
If you want to center the nav, you only need to set the property `align-text: center` in the parent `div`of the main nav. and if you want to click all the box instead only the text, the element that needs the padding and margin is the `a` not the `li`.

Check the snippet:

```css
span{
display:block;
font-size:100px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.index {
    background-image: url("images/indexbackground.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 1600px 800px;
}

.navwrapperindex {
  text-align: center;
}
.navwrapperindex > nav{
  display: inline-block;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    font-family: Arial;
}

ul {
  background: black;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    color: #white;
  background: black;    
    float: left;    
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 27px;
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
    background: #DEB887;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
    background: black;
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 17rem;
    position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
    left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<center><span>The Piano</span></center>

<!--(start) NAVBAR-->
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<nav>
  <div class="navwrapperindex">
    <nav class="navmenuindex">
      <ul class="clearfixindex">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a>The piano itself</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="mechanics.html">Mechanics</a></li>
            <li><a href="construction.html">Construction</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a>Types of pianos</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="grand.html">Grand</a></li>
              <li><a href="upright.html">Upright</a></li>
              <li><a href="electric.html">Electric</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="historypianos.html">History of the piano</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="pianosongs.html">Piano songs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a livesaver. I'm sorry but I have one more question, the navigation bar is now extended to full width but I want it to "float" in the center, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: That's bacause you are setting a `background-color: black` in all the `nav` elements, you can either remove that property or just specify it in the inner `nav`. Check the snippet updated.

Comment: Ah, I get it now! Thank you, you've helped me a lot!